# php: compound if statement (is being ignored)

Tags: php, if-statement

I want to echo something if the subdomain is not "mobile" and the file name is not "design" or "photo", so echo if (not "mobile" and not "design") or (not "mobile" and not "photo").

The code I wrote is:

```
<?php
    if ( ($subdomain != mobile) && ($currentFileName != design || $currentFileName != photo) ) {
        echo ('code')
    }
?>
```

but it doesn't like the compound statement. if i just do `($subdomain!=mobile)` it works; if i just do `($currentFileName!=design)` it works; and if i just do `($currentFileName!=photo)` it works….
The above code doesn't result in an error…it just doesn't do anything.

Is there a particular way to compound/group the statement that I'm just not getting? I feel like this shouldn't be difficult (and I've done much more complex things with php without this much trouble…).
I modelled my statement after this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php#101724

Thanks!

EDIT:
fyi:

```
$subdomain = implode(array_slice(array_reverse(explode('.', $baseURL)),2)); //resolves to "test"
$basename = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); //resolves to "design.php"
$currentFileName = basename($basename, ".php"); //resolves to "design"
```

the new problem is that everything in the subdomain "mobile" is now being caught, so no pages in it are getting the "code" from echo (even the ones not 'design' or 'photo').

the most recent code I tried was:

```
if ( ($subdomain != 'test' && $currentFileName != 'design') && ($subdomain!='test' && $currentFileName != 'photo') ) {
    echo ('ajax code');
}
```

but still no dice :(

Comment: Also, the semicolon after `echo`.

Comment: Your || portion of the statement will fail for everything. You're saying something cannot be two different things at the same time, which would always be true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a flaw in your logic.  You most likely want `&&` not `||`.  If you think about the statement for a minute it will become apparent.  Let's say the following scenario:  $currentFileName is 'design'.  It will pass since it's not 'photo'.  If we make $currentFileName equal 'photo' it will still pass since it doesn't equal 'design'.

EDIT:
And PLEASE use quotes when comparing strings.  PHP will attempt to find a constant with that name first, then assume it's a string because it doesn't find one.

Comment: The other pages in "mobile" are not getting the "code" from the echo. I think what's happening is it's getting to the $subdomain != 'mobile' and stopping because the subdomain is "mobile" but the page is not 'design' or 'photo' (it's 'about'). I tried putting the two conditions together like this:
if ( ($subdomain != 'mobile' && $currentFileName != 'design') && ($subdomain != 'mobile' && $currentFileName != 'photo') ) {
echo ('ajax code');
}
but that doesn't make the ajax code show up on subdomain="mobile" for pages that aren't 'design' or 'photo' :(

Comment: @Jacob Try `if (!($subdomain == "mobile" && ($currentFileName == "design" || $currentFileName == "photo")))`

Comment: ahhh! you're a genius. that's what i would have done in shell script, but i didn't know you could do an "if not" with php. oh and thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Replace `||` to `&&` - there should be 'AND'

```
if ( ($subdomain != 'mobile') && ($currentFileName != 'design' && $currentFileName != 'photo') ) {
        echo ('code');
    }
```

Comment: @jacob: Make sure get rid of the parentheses first before someone looks at you funny ;)

Answer (score 0):

I understand it should be:

```
<?php
    if ($subdomain != 'mobile' && $currentFileName != 'design' && $currentFileName != 'photo') {
        echo ('code');
    }
?>
```

Because the 'or' make it to match any file name, including 'design' and 'photo'.

Good point, quotes added :)

Comment: I just added the ';' in the echo line.

Comment: btw, i originally had quotes, but then i got a syntax parse error saying '"' was unexpected on line 63 (where the quotes for this were).

Answer (score 0):

If you're comparing strings, you should quote them. Otherwise, it thinks they are constants.

Try:

```
<?php
if ( ($subdomain != 'mobile') && ($currentFileName != 'design' || $currentFileName != 'photo') ) {
  echo 'code';
}
?>
```

If that still doesn't work as expected, debug `$subdomain` and `$currentFileName` to ensure they are what you think.

**Note:** per the comments it would seem that you're logic is incorrect as well.

Comment: I think the 'or' is not right, any filename will be not equal one of them, including 'design' and 'photo'.

Comment: @morgar, agreed. But I can't speak to the user's logic :)

Comment: i just added this above, but: $subdomain resolves to "test" or "m" (mobile). $currentFileName resolves to "design" or "photo" or "about" (it is a basename - .php)

Comment: No worries. Sounds like you got it solved above. I didn't adjust your logic anyway.