# Compound PHP statement not working

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm having issues with getting this bit of code working. I want if a certain page loads this template, and 1 of 4 possible categories are specified to then execute this action.

```
if (is_page('combined-feed') and ($event_category=='179' || 
    $event_category=='180' || $event_category=='181' || 
    $event_category=='1028')) 
{
    $description = "description goes here"; 
}
```

I tried using a structure similar to what is found in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037173/php-compound-if-statement-is-being-ignored), but have had no luck getting it to meet the criteria of the if statement. I know there's something going wrong with the or statements, but haven't been able to figure out how to structure the code any better.

**Update:** Turns out there was nothing structurally wrong with this code, I just had an issue with another if statement.

Comment: And what does *no luck getting it to work* mean? Any errors? Tell us: `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>`

Comment: What does `var_dump((is_page('combined-feed'))` show? What does `var_export($event_category)` show?

Comment: No errors, just not returning anything. This is part of a larger if statement, I just boiled it down to the single statement.

Comment: @jamEs Show us your **full** and **real** code

Comment: @jamEs If you don't dump the values requested by John (above), there is nothing we can do.

Comment: @Rizier123 It's a much larger Wordpress RSS template. I know $event_category will return a singular value in each RSS item. I'm just not sure why it won't handle checking against multiple values.

Comment: When I did var_export($event_category) for each item in my RSS feed it returned either 179,180,181 or 1028.

Comment: @jamEs And what is the output of: `var_dump((is_page('combined-feed'));` ?

Comment: @Rizier123 it doesn't return anything, just outputs the text "var_dump((is_page('combined-feed'))" instead of returning a value. Sorry, I'm a real novice with PHP when it comes to this stuff, hence why I'm asking for help structuring an if statement.

Comment: What is the output ? post it here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write the code this way

```
if (is_page('combined-feed') && ($event_category=='179' || 
    $event_category=='180' || $event_category=='181' || 
    $event_category=='1028')) 
{
    $description = "description goes here"; 
}
```

In your way, || operators are evaluated first and 'and' operator last, because 'and' has lower precedence than '||'.

See [PHP Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)